# writing logs into mounted volume not working in Docker

Tags: docker

I created a volume by name 'logf'.

Then I run my app-1
docker run -v /var/log=/logf app-1

I use /lof to write logs. but it is not able to write logs. where am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is not correct, use this instead

```
docker run -v logf:/var/log app-1
```

It mounts the volume `logf` as `/var/log` into the container.

Comment: Tried that. didnt work.Docker command :  sudo docker run -ti -e LOGFILE=logf -v /logf=/var/log/agent.log app-1
Dokerfile: CMD [ "sh", "-c", "python /conf/app.py ${LOGFILE}"]          \Python code logger = logging.getLogger('app1')
hdlr = logging.FileHandler(sys.argv[1])

Comment: Am referring to mount point name in code to write log. Am expecting it to be written into /var/log/agent.log. for that I also tried /var/log/agent.log=/logf and reverse way as well.

Comment: So I should mount directory from container to host directory? For that I should know where it is writing in container?

Comment: Check again what you typed and what I wrote. The logf does not have a leading / and I used : instead of =.